# (odoo10) how to add product attributes in pdf invoice

Tags: pdf, odoo, odoo-10

pls advice how to add product attributes into pdf invoice.
Currently we printing product SCU:

> ```
>                     <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
>                     <td><span t-field="l.product_id.default_code"/></td>
>                     <td class="hidden"><span t-field="l.origin"/></td>
>                     <td class="text-right">
> ```

and it looks a bit ugly on invoice.
pls advice how to add product template like l.product_id.name + attributes, like:
[image]

also, could you pls advice how to put attributes below product name?
here is my code now:

```
        <tbody class="invoice_tbody">
            <tr t-foreach="o.invoice_line_ids" t-as="l">
                <td><span t-field="l.product_id.name"/></td>
                <t t-esc="', '.join(['%s: %s' % (attribute_value.attribute_id.name, attribute_value.name) for attribute_value in l.product_id.attribute_value_ids])"/>
                <td class="hidden"><span t-field="l.origin"/></td>
```

i'd like to have it like that:
[image]
many thanks in advance!

Comment: it's the same answer, just use it like this:

    <td>
        <div>
            <span t-field="l.product_id.name"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <t t-esc="', '.join(['%s: %s' % (attribute_value.attribute_id.name, attribute_value.name) for attribute_value in l.product_id.attribute_value_ids])"/>
        </div>
    </td>

Comment: great, many thanks, answer accepted!

Comment: please upvote, it helps too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something like this to output the product attributes name and value:

```
<t t-esc="', '.join(['%s: %s' % (attribute_value.attribute_id.name, attribute_value.name) for attribute_value in l.product_id.attribute_value_ids])"/>:
```

Comment: Axel, many thanks, it's almost what i need, but could you pls advice how to put attributes below product name? i will update my initial question in 2 minutes.

Comment: It's a matter of position, see the other comment. But the answer to your question should be the posted one